# Want to create a dataframe from multiple for loops

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I am running the following code to create a DataFrame , need to change the print statements, tried a bunch of stuff like creating a blank df first, then appending,but the dataframe gets overwritten at every loop. Am quite new at this, help is a lot appreciated. [This is the desired result, need it as a dataframe][1]

````py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import selenium.common.exceptions
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
catlink=['https://www.daraz.com.bd/camera-lenses','https://www.daraz.com.bd/small-kitchen-appliances/','https://www.daraz.com.bd/bedding-bath/']


for link in catlink:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(10)
    for i in range(0,8):
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]').click()
            time.sleep(4)
            i+=1
            elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > div:nth-child(2) > div.c2xMr_ > div.ant-carousel > div > div.slick-list>* a")
            for element in elements:
                # want to create a dataframe from these two blocks: check the screen shot for the desired result
                print('mainlink:'+str(link)+str(driver.title) +':'+ str(element.get_attribute("href")))

        except (selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException):
            print('mainlink:'+str(link)+str(driver.title) +':No Banners')
            continue ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5ICz.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `append` in loop values in list and last call `DataFrame` constructor:

````
L = []
for link in catlink:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(10)
    for i in range(0,8):
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]').click()
            time.sleep(4)
            i+=1
            elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > div:nth-child(2) > div.c2xMr_ > div.ant-carousel > div > div.slick-list>* a")
            for element in elements:
                # want to create a dataframe from these two blocks: check the screen shot for the desired result
                print('mainlink:'+str(link)+str(driver.title) +':'+ str(element.get_attribute("href")))
                L.append(str(link)+str(driver.title) +':'+ str(element.get_attribute("href")))

        except (selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException):
            print('mainlink:'+str(link)+str(driver.title) +':No Banners')
            continue ```

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['mainlink'])
````

If need 3 columns in `DataFrame` append tuples:

````
L = []
for link in catlink:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(10)
    for i in range(0,8):
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]').click()
            time.sleep(4)
            i+=1
            elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > div:nth-child(2) > div.c2xMr_ > div.ant-carousel > div > div.slick-list>* a")
            for element in elements:
                # want to create a dataframe from these two blocks: check the screen shot for the desired result
                print('mainlink:'+str(link)+str(driver.title) +':'+ str(element.get_attribute("href")))
                L.append((str(link), str(driver.title), str(element.get_attribute("href")))

        except (selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException):
            print('mainlink:'+str(link)+str(driver.title) +':No Banners')
            continue ```

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['link','title','href'])
````

Answer (score 0):

append tuples (which is row of your dataframe) of your values to urls in loop and create dataframe with it at end

```py
urls = []
for link in catlink:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(10)
    for i in range(0,8):
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]').click()
            time.sleep(4)
            i+=1
            elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > div:nth-child(2) > div.c2xMr_ > div.ant-carousel > div > div.slick-list>* a")
            for element in elements:
                # want to create a dataframe from these two blocks: check the screen shot for the desired result
                print('mainlink:'+str(link)+str(driver.title) +':'+ str(element.get_attribute("href")))
                urls.append((str(link)+str(driver.title), str(element.get_attribute("href")))
        except (selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException):
            print('mainlink:'+str(link)+str(driver.title) +':No Banners')
            urls.append((str(link)+str(driver.title), ':No Banners'))
            continue 

result = pd.DataFrame(urls, columns=["mainlink", "banner"])
```